# "[app name] appears to be infected. Immediate uninstallation is advised" pop-up on Huawei devices

Tags: huawei, popup

I just got a pop-up on my phone, Huawei P30 lite running Emui 10.

It was approximately:

> Asana appears to be infected. Immediate uninstallation is advised.

I do not use Asana currently so uninstalled to be safe, but it made me wonder:

1. Is there actually an infection?
2. Where does the message come from, I have never seen one like it
3. Where would I go to confirm the official message, I just went to the Asana main page and didn't notice anything unusual, but suppose these things may be placed in a corner somewhere

Comment: If someone has the exact message I can update the text for searchability, also I found some page where someone noticed the same thing today but without insights https://forum.asana.com/t/virus-warning-regarding-the-asana-app-on-my-huawei-smartphone/150361/1

Comment: I updated the message after doing quick research (btw, the screenshot on the Asana forum actually shows the exact message).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This is an alert pop-up from Avast Antivirus that is integrated on some Huawei/EMUI devices.**

Regarding the actual infection, it's hard to say, but based on online reports about the pop-up, looks like most of them were false positive:

- [MIT App Inventor Help - Why My Compiled App With Trojan / App has virus](https://community.appinventor.mit.edu/t/why-my-compiled-app-with-trojan-app-has-virus/1607) (and its linked discussions)
- [PiunikaWeb - [Update: Lloyds Bank & others too] Halifax Bank app 'Security threat' pop-up issue on Android gets acknowledged](https://piunikaweb.com/2022/01/22/halifax-bank-app-security-threat-pop-up-issue-on-android-acknowledged/) (22 Jan 2022)
- [Monzo app “appears to be infected”](https://community.monzo.com/t/monzo-app-appears-to-be-infected/128192) (21 Jan 2022)
- Reddit:

  - [Security Threat, App appears to be infected](https://www.reddit.com/r/Huawei/comments/s9w9e2/security_threat_app_appears_to_be_infected/) (22 Jan 2022)
  - [No, your phone does not have an infected app. It is a weird bug with Huawei devices going on right now.](https://www.reddit.com/r/Huawei/comments/sa192z/no_your_phone_does_not_have_an_infected_app_it_is/) (22 Jan 2022)

Also on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Huawei/comments/le1tox/comment/grl1br1/?utm_source=reddit&utm_medium=web2x&context=3), there was a suggestion to update the virus database.

> Open the "Optimizer" app, that should have shipped by default with any modern Huawei smartphone. Tap the gear icon in the top right corner to open the settings dialog.
>
> The last option in that list is called "Online Virus Scan". If the last update was many days ago, you can manually update by tapping "Online Virus Scan" and selecting "WLAN only".

As to how to confirm the official message, unfortunately, Avast does not seem to provide any more detail other than only letting the user choose to ignore/uninstall the app.

- One way is to contact them by any means, like public forums (preferable, so other users can give more input), or even call their customer support directly.
- Another way is to cross-scan the app with multiple scanners (e.g. [VirusTotal](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/)). One can retrieve the APK file by downloading it from reliable alternative sources (e.g. [APKMirror](https://www.apkmirror.com/)), then uploading it there.

  [Here](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/bfd6b77951789991d36a4bdd62d78a464647851642721ab7816b6eb91ed1dbbc/detection) is the scan result for [Asana 6.84.3](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/asana/asana/asana-6-84-3-release/) (20 Jan 2022).

Comment: Just saw this pop-up out of the blue for the first time, "Swift Backup appears to be infected. Immediate uninstallation is advised". I hadn't updated Swift Backup in *months*, so it seems that the antivirus signatures got updated very recently. BTW, I've been using this phone since 2019, and had no idea there was an "antivirus" bundled in EMUI.

Comment: Same story, "Google infected...", downgraded, full scan with free versions of Avira and AVG found nothing, updated Optimizer, update Google again, popup immediately back. Android 9.10, Huawei y6 2019.

Comment: me too just today